# Setting percentage width of Wowslider caption title

Tags: javascript, jquery, wowslider

does anyone know how to correctly set the percentage width of the Wowslider caption title?

I set .ws-title-wrapper and .ws-title as 70% in the CSS file but now the caption title expands from 50% to 70% after the slide in effect is complete. Needless to say it looks stupid.

Thanks!

Chris

Answer (score 0):

I ended up setting a fixed pixel width for .ws-title-wrapper and .ws-title and media queries to scale the caption title down for smaller devices. That seems to work.